# Using JavaScript to determine the middle div, within a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, carousel

I've created a basic multi-item horizontal carouse, which moves through a div of images, when you click either a "left" or "right" button.

I want to write some JavaScript logic, which tells me which div, is the most centered div on screen, within the container DOM node:\

```
<section class="items-container"></section>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('app.js loaded');

  const pixabayAPIService = PixabayAPIService();
  const carouselContainer = document.getElementById('carousel-container');
  const previousButton    = document.getElementById('previous');
  const nextButton        = document.getElementById('next');
  let count               = 0;

  console.log('count', count);

  pixabayAPIService.getImages();

  slideImages = (direction) => {
    const totalChildren = carouselContainer.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
    console.log('totalChildren', totalChildren);

    direction === 'left' ? count ++ : count --;
    console.log('updated count', count);

    carouselContainer.classList.add('horizTranslate');
    carouselContainer.style.left = count * 200 + 'px';
    carouselContainer.classList.add("slideOutLeft")

    previousButton.style.display = count < 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    nextButton.style.display = count > 5 - totalChildren ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  previousButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    slideImages('left');
  });

  nextButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    slideImages('right');
  });

  if (count === -1) {

  }
});
```

```css
.home-product-new-hldr {
    position: relative;
    /* width:1140px; */
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 1000px;
}

.carousel-container {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

.items-container {
    border: 3px solid green;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    position:relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.item {
    border: 0px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.horizTranslate {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
  <body>

    <main>
      <h1>Carousel</h1>

      <section>
          <button id="previous" style="display: none;">left</button>
        </section>

      <div class="frame">
      <div class="carousel-container">
      <section class="items-container" id="carousel-container" style="left: 0px; border: 1px solid red";>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100" /></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section>
      <button id="next" style="display: block;">right</button>
    </section>

  </main>

  </body>
```

Yes, there are 6 divs listed there, but when I make my carousel responsive, the number of carousel items within the div will reduce.

So I wanted to know the best way, to calculate the most centered div, within the `section` node, regardless of screen/device.

Thank you.

Comment: Ideally the javascript would know which element is in the front by virtue of having put it there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript, we can loop through each of the child DIVs and find which is the most centered by comparing it's left and right edges with the center of the carousel. Here's a [CodePen example of the below code in action](https://codepen.io/calebkm/pen/XWWVLZj):

```js
function getMostCentered(container, items) {
  // Find center of the container
  let container_bounds = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
      center = container_bounds.left + (container_bounds.width / 2);

  // Loop through each item and compare with the center
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let item = items[i],
        next = items[i+1],
        item_bounds = item.getBoundingClientRect(),
        next_bounds = next && next.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Find the first item whose left edge is past the center 
    if (next && next_bounds.left > center) {
      // and compare it with the previous item to see which is closer
      if (next_bounds.left - center < center - item_bounds.right) {
        return next;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    // If we've hit the last item then it must be closest
    } else if (!next) {
      return item
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Calebkm!  This is really awesome, as I have never heard of bounds before, or done any JS work with calculating widths etc. So very cool, as I'm learning something new! :D I kinda get what you're doing, I need to have a good read through and break it down.... Did this work for you btw?  I'm getting a few undefined, but no worries, I'm looking forward to getting this working. AWESOME solution - thank you!!!

Comment: Hey @calebkm - was wondering you could explain this main if condition -        if (next.left - center < center - current.right) - don't quite understand the calculation...

Comment: Sure! Have a look at this CodePen example: https://codepen.io/calebkm/pen/XWWVLZj The conditional is comparing the GREEN left-hand edge of the `next` element with the MAGENTA right-hand edge of the `current` element - to check which is the closest to the RED center of the section. The edge that is closer to the center belongs to the item that is the "most" centered. Feel free to play around and adjust the sizing of things in the CodePen example to get a better feel for what the JS is doing. Let me know if that helps!